# ffmpeg script only running for first in list?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I wrote a small script that converts HQ video to LQ:

```
ls video/hq | cut -d. -f1 | while read line ; do
  HQ=./video/hq/$line.mp4
  LQ=./video/lq/$line.mp4
  ffmpeg -i $HQ -crf 40 $LQ
done;
```

When I run `ls video/hq | cut -d. f1` I get back:

```
1502460615677
1502461135975
1502461292963
1502461373947
1502461493936
1502461782119
```

But when running the conversion script only `1502460615677` is processed.

If I replace the line with `ffmpeg` with `echo $line` echo runs for all but with `ffmpeg` it only runs for one.

Anyone know why ffmpeg changes how this runs?

Comment: Aside from [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) I don't see a problem. Add `set -x` to see what commands are actually running.

Comment: @glennjackman before ffmpeg runs I get `+read line` and then the script ends so no new information.

Comment: @glennjackman strange if I switch my `ffmpeg` command for `echo` it works fine. It seems like ffmpeg breaks out of the loop or something(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `ffmpeg` reads from standard input, which interferes with the `read` command. So I'm directing to `/dev/null`

```
ls video/hq | cut -d. -f1 | while read line ; do
  HQ=./video/hq/$line.mp4
  LQ=./video/lq/$line.mp4
  ffmpeg -i $HQ -crf 40 $LQ < /dev/null
done;
```